# Do achievement related bonusses apply in ME2?

Tags: achievements, mass-effect-2, mass-effect-series

I've recently started playing mass-effect again -- lost interest in it when losing my save file due to a hard disk crash --, seeing how reasonably well priced ME2 is and how it looks and as I want to import an existing save file.

I've completed one play through and am advancing on my second one to achieve level 60. But I'm not planning to complete the majority of the game *again* unless this would prove to be useful.

Therefore my question: Do achievement related bonuses (such as the EXP earned rising by 10% by completing the majority of the game) apply in mass-effect 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the "Rich" achievement, individual achievements in ME1 don't affect ME2. There are however bonuses for reaching Level 60, which some ME1 achievements will help you do.

See http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Save_File_Transfer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Sykora provided, I'll mention that if you *do* want the effects of those achievements, and/or simply a different Shepard to import, [Mass Effect Saves](http://www.masseffectsaves.com/) exists to provide you with the proper scenarios without re-investing playtime into ME 1.

Or radically different ones, if you prefer.

If your question is actually "Do achievements in ME1 provide gameplay benefits in ME2", the answer is a resounding "No". You can start with more experience and resources, but since both are quite plentiful (your main limiter in ME2, contrary to ME1, is credits) *anyway*, you don't miss out on any power bonus, mechanically speaking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't like to import something I didn't realy achieved myself though, so I'm going to complete the game again :)

Comment: @Anzeo +1 Hardcore gamer.

Comment: Main limiter is credits?  For me it's always been platinum.

Comment: @Mason - You can turn credits into platinum, though, with enough probes / fuel.

Answer (score 1):

The best advantage you can have is your Paragon and Renegade scores. With those high in ME2, you can get good conversation options. At one point you can get Morinth instead of Samara if you have a high PR score. It also helps with the loyalty of squad members at the end.

Comment: Not quite true -- The way Paragon / Renegade actions are handled in ME2 is based off (alignment points) / (total possible alignment points) -- if you *always* pick the paragon action, when available, you will never fail a paragon check. The benefit of importing is that you can *dabble* between the two, as the transfered points aren't taken into the alignment calculations to determine whether the related option was available. This is vastly different compared to ME1, where you could fully accumulate Paragon *and* Renegade points. ME2 makes you choose.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I assume you need the actual points (in the bar) and not just the Renegade 'skill' maxed out?